# Cannot install Subclipse plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I cannot install Subclipse both from "install new software" and Eclipse Marketplace.

When I try to install Subclipse 4.2.3, I got this:
[image]

For the second option "Update my installation to be compatible with the items being installed":
[image]

For the third option "Show original error and build my own solution", I got following error:

```
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Subclipse 4.2.3.201707071932 (org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group 4.2.3.201707071932)
  Software currently installed: Subversion Client Adapter (Required) 1.10.3 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group 1.10.3)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Subversion Client Adapter 1.10.3 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter 1.10.3)
    Subversion Client Adapter 1.9.4.2 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter 1.9.4.2)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Subversion Client Adapter (Required) 1.10.3 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group 1.10.3)
    To: org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter [1.10.3]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Subclipse 4.2.3.201707071932 (org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group 4.2.3.201707071932)
    To: org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter [1.9.4.2]
```

(I guess the reason is here! I may have installed Subversion Client Adapter some version already. But I cannot see it from Eclipse. If this is the problem, could you tell me where to uninstall it?)

After I selected the second option, I got this error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_eclipse_jee-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.collabnet.subversion.merge,4.2.0.1
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.trilead.ssh2,1.0.0.build220_r167_v20150618_1733
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter,1.9.4.2
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl,1.9.4.1
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit,1.8.12.1
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature,1.8.12.1
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core,4.2.3.201707071932
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.tigris.subversion.subclipse,4.2.3.201707071932
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui,4.2.3.201707071932
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tmatesoft.sqljet,1.1.10.r1317_v20140121_0107
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tmatesoft.svnkit,1.8.12.r10533_v20160129_0158
```

When I try to install Subclipse 1.10.x from "http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x", I got this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_eclipse_jee-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl,1.8.15
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64,1.8.15
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.mylyn,3.0.0
```

My environment:

- Windows 10, 64 bits
- Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
- SVN 1.8.17(r1770682)
- Java version "1.8.0_121", Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server    VM (build
  25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: First [upgrade your IDE](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F) and then try again.

Comment: @howlger Yeah, upgraded, but still does not work

Comment: Now, what happens if you choose option 2 (_Update my installation_)? It looks like you have an old version of Subclipse installed.

Comment: @howlger Hi, tried the second option, I got exactly same problem as I said in my question.

Comment: What have you installed of Subclipse/Subversion/SVN Adapters and can you uninstall it (in _Help > About Eclipse_ click _Installation Details_, in tab _Installed Software_ select it and click _Uninstall..._)?

Comment: @howlger Thank you!! It works!! Before I only checked the installed softwares in Marketplace, but in the Installation Details.  You can answer my question, I will mark it as the solution. :)

Comment: Great. Please edit my answer if it is not correct or inaccurate.

Comment: Sometimes,  changing "https" of the eclipse update site URL to "http" works.

Comment: What happened to http://subclipse.tigris.org ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have installed an older version of Subclipse (see your second screenshot).

Try to **uninstall the older version first**: in ***Help > About Eclipse*** click ***Installation Details***, in tab ***Installed Software*** select the Subclipse, Subversion, SVN Adapters, etc. and click ***Uninstall...***

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after updating Eclipse SDP (RAD and RDi bundle), but I did not have Subclipse listed in my Installation Details (despite it being installed prior to the update). Re-installing Subclipse from eclipse Marketplace and then again using the "Install New Software" prompt resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but, I had this issue recently installing SVN in IBM Integration toolkit. I was able to resolve the issue so might be helpful for someone else too. Click Help - Install new software, then add link https://subclipse.github.io/updates/  and go thru installation. This worked for me after spending couple of hours.